# Which Intents/Broadcasts could be "sticky" in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Where can I find information which `Intent/Broadcast` can be sticky?

Example of a sticky broadcast sent via the operating system is [ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED). When I call `registerReceiver()` for that action with a `null` `BroadcastReceiver` — I get the `Intent` that was last Broadcast for that action.

Whenever I find the last value by:

```
//In Activity
val batteryIntent = registerReceiver(null, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)); //sticky
val level = batteryIntent?.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
val scale = batteryIntent?.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
```

This Intent: `AudioManager.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` works too, but some Intents don't work: `LocationManager.MODE_CHANGED_ACTION`, `Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED`, ... I know, some don't make sense, but result of these Intents are always `null`, even if there has been a change, why?

For `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` there is information: "This is a sticky broadcast ..." in doc, but for `ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG` no.

Is exist any restriction or split to sticky / non-sticky or list which Intents work as sticky?
Why do some Intents work and others don't?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Where can I find information which `Intent`/Broadcast can be sticky?

Look at the source code for the Android version of interest, searching for `sendStickyBroadcast()`.

> Is exist any restriction or split to sticky / non-sticky or list which Intents work as sticky?

Sticky broadcasts are sent using `sendStickyBroadcast()`. Technically, it is not tied to a specific `Intent`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it a better way to search than: https://cs.android.com/search?q=function:sendStickyBroadcast()&sq= ? There all a lot usages.

Comment: @t0m: Many of those uses are test code and stuff. I don't know enough about that site's options to know what sort of filtering options might be useful. But, yes, in general, that is what I was thinking.